# Determining a value in an algorithm on its first run

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, approximation

I was given the following algorithm as a solution to one of my problems.
However, I am baffled at understanding how c' is ever initialized. The first if statement can never be reached, as c' is never set the first time. Can someone explain this to me? Am I just missing where c' gets set?

This is for Kleinberg and Tardos, Chapter 11, Question 12.

[image]

Comment: It’s a typo - should be $c’=$ instead of $c’-$ in line 5.

Comment: Hey @YuvalFilmus, thanks. My professor sent this to me with NO explanation, just that my initial answer was wrong and this was right...
Can you please post that as an answer so that I may accept it as a correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting [Yuval Filmus's comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/101369/determining-a-value-in-an-algorithm-on-its-first-run#comment216276_101369) as an answer since they didn't:

> It’s a typo - should be $c’=$ instead of $c’-$ in line 5.